# How to get the Pixel Android 7.1 Navigation bar back?

Tags: settings, google-pixel

My brother has recently used the "factory reset" option on his Google Pixel XL phone, this made the navigation bar to change from the traditional 
[image]

to one where the circular one in the middle is a solid disk (as in the first bar below).
[image]
I have been looking for a way to get the original navigation bar back, but all I found were "artificial ways" whose purpose is to get this navigation bar to other Android phones. Is there a natural way to get the default navigation bar back? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was changing the language from English to a less common one. Once it was changed back to English the issue has been resolved.